# Control-M avoid cyclic job from run before prev day's complete

Tags: control-m

I have a Control-M job that runs every 20 min.  Everything works great during that day's run.  The issue is when we auto-order the next days jobs.  If the current day's jobs are running we get 2 copies of the jobs running at the same time.

Is there a way to not start the new job if the previous day's job is executing?

Answer (score 1):

The job starts every 20 minutes, but how long does it run?  Set the end window for "submit between" time a few minutes before the new day build.

Let's say your new day builds at 0400.  Since the job is intended to run every 20 minutes, you can have it run as late as 0340.  Set the "to" time in Activity Window to 0340 and the job won't autosubmit after that time.  The new day will build at 0400 and the new version of the job will start then - 20 minutes after the previous start.

You can also add a control resource to the job to prevent two of them from running at the same time. I don't know another way to do it.  That's not a can of worms I'd open unless the activity period settings just won't work the way you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to last day's job execution bleeding into current day, causing resource contention, your best bet (as Rob pointed out) is to define a resource with max count of 1 to be required by the job, so next day job instance cannot start until prev day job completes and release the resource. Alternatively you can have the job post a Condition for order date + 1, and have order date condition also be an In condition for the job.